# Does Visual Studio 2010 Professional support UML modeling?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

Does Visual Studio 2010 Professional support UML modeling? I see a blog tutorial showing it in an online template, but online template browsing is not available. I even enabled the following trick to add it:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

This doesn't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is supported within [Ultimate](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate).

> The Architecture Explorer in Visual
>   Studio 2010 Ultimate helps you
>   understand your existing code assets
>   and their interdependencies. Layer
>   diagramming helps ensure architectural
>   compliance and allows you to validate
>   code artifacts against the diagram.
>   Plus Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
>   supports the five most common UML
>   diagrams that live alongside your
>   code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the comparison chart: [VISUAL STUDIO 2010 COMPARISON](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison)