# Adding UML to Visual Studio 2010 Premium?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml

I would like to add a UML tool to my Visual Studio 2010 Premium.  It looks like it might be an Ultimate only thing as stated here -> [Does Visual Studio 2010 Professional support UML modeling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647838/does-visual-studio-2010-professional-support-uml-modeling).  I'm not finding anything adding UML support to Premium.

If it true that it is an Ultimate only thing, what UML tools are people using outside of Visual Studio?

I'm new to UML and trying to figure out how to do my designs better with less revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these:

- Enterprise Architect
- Magic Draw - I have used this and it is very
  good and does alot. Can be daunting so maybe overkill if you are just
  getting going with UML.

Both of these require licenses. I am not aware of any *decent* free UML tools. But then I am not an authority on UML tools!

Edit:

Just remembered that Altova also have a UML tool - I have not used this. However, I have used their XSD suite and can verify that their software quality is very good, so the UML tool may also be good.

Comment: Magic Draw starts around $600, ouch.  Enterprise Architect starts around $135.

Comment: Yup - the last time I used Magic Draw (2 years ago) they claimed to be the only fully UML2 compliant tool on the market - I can not verify if that is true.

Comment: For the price of Magic Draw I stopped the demo version from downloading.  Enterprise Architect was OK, a little clunky.  I have been using RISE editor, but it doesn't have use case tools and is a little clunky.  So far nothing about learning UML and the tools to design with it has been easy.

Comment: I remembered Altova do a UML tool - see my edit... And there is always the classic Rational Rose suite from IBM. Again, I have not used it and I suspect that it will not be cheap.

Comment: Saw your edit and downloaded the demo of Altova.  Altova's UML tool UModel Basic version is only $150.  Seems very nice.  Looks like it has everything I am looking for, and is less clunky than the others.  Thanks RobertMS!

Comment: Pleasure - hope you enjoy getting to grips with UML!

Answer (score 1):

StarUML is one of the better UML diagram tools out there and it is free. If you do a diligent enough job with the design, it'll even auto-generate headers and source skeletons.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ultimate edition and also acess to Sparx EA but my tool of choice is Visio with these excellent free UML [stencils](http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html). The advantage of Visio is it allows to use many shapes (non - UML) in the same diagram and it is free with MSDN. I am not an UML purist and doesn't require all bells and whistles for my diagrams.

An architect I once met used [Agilian](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/ag/) which seems to be a capable tool as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Without MSDN Visio starts around $500 and Agilian starts around $300